# Gitlab rpm version

Tags: centos, yum, rpm, gitlab

It is [recommended](https://about.gitlab.com/installation/) to installed Gitlab as a Omnibus package. Packages are  available for the popular deb and rpm formats. Packages are available [here](https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ee?filter=rpms).
There is a also script that automates installation.
There are the following recent packages available for CentOS users:

- gitlab-ee-8.5.0-ee.**1.el6**.x86_64.rpm # Enterprise Linux 6.0 (CentOS, RedHat, Amazon Linux)
- gitlab-ee-8.5.0-ee.**0.el6**.x86_64.rpm # See above
- gitlab-ee-8.5.0-ee.**1.el7**.x86_64.rpm # Enterprise Linux 7.0 (CentOS, RedHat, Amazon Linux)
- gitlab-ee-8.5.0-ee.**0.el7**.x86_64.rpm # See above

What is the difference between **0**.el6 and **1**.el6?

I'm running CentOS release 6.7 (Final) with a kernel release Linux 2.6.32-573.7.1.el6.x86_64. Should I choose gitlab-ee-8.5.0-ee.**1.el6.x86_64**.rpm?

Comment: Why not ask Gitlab?

Comment: @EEAA Thanks for the tip. I thought it could be some general rpm naming convention. Like el6 for CentOS 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand RPM versioning it's helpful to look at how `yum` treats things. When I install the GitLab package repository and run `yum info gitlab-ee --showduplicates` I get the following output (shortened):

```
    Name        : gitlab-ee
    Arch        : x86_64
    Version     : 8.5.0
    Release     : ee.0.el7
    Size        : 282 M
    Repo        : gitlab_gitlab-ee/x86_64
    Summary     : GitLab Enterprise Edition and GitLab CI (including NGINX, Postgres, Redis)
    URL         : https://about.gitlab.com/
    License     : unknown
    Description : GitLab Enterprise Edition and GitLab CI (including NGINX, Postgres, Redis)

    Name        : gitlab-ee
    Arch        : x86_64
    Version     : 8.5.0
    Release     : ee.1.el7
    Size        : 282 M
    Repo        : gitlab_gitlab-ee/x86_64
    Summary     : GitLab Enterprise Edition and GitLab CI (including NGINX, Postgres, Redis)
    URL         : https://about.gitlab.com/
    License     : unknown
    Description : GitLab Enterprise Edition and GitLab CI (including NGINX, Postgres, Redis)
```

Notice the `Release` value for each. `yum` outputs the newest package at the bottom and you can see the bottom `Release` value is `ee.1.el7`. `yum` uses the combination of version and release to determine the newest package to install. In this case we (GitLab) had some issue in the `ee.0.el7` package but not in the GitLab code itself so we repackaged it as `ee.1.el7`. The actual GitLab version is the same (`8.5.0`).

I hope this helps explain RPM versioning. I highly recommend adding the YUM repos

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. This question had occurred, because it is mentioned in the upgrade page: # CentOS:
sudo rpm -Uvh gitlab-x.x.x_xxx.rpm [source](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/doc/update/README.md#updating-from-gitlab-66-and-higher-to-the-latest-version). I will try to use repository as you suggested following this [manual](https://about.gitlab.com/upgrade-to-package-repository/#centos)